# python subprocess popen: Piping stdout messes up the strings

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.4

I am trying to concatenate a couple of files together and add a header.

```
import subprocess
outpath = "output.tab"
with open( outpath, "w" ) as outf :
        "write a header"
        if header is True:
            p1 = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-n1", files[-1] ], stdout= outf, )
        if type(header) is str:
            p1 = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-n1", header ], stdout= outf,)
        for fl in files:
            print(  fl )
            p1 = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n+2", fl], stdout= outf, )
```

for some reason some files (`fl`) are printed only partially and next file starts amid of a string from a previous file:

```
 awk '{print NF}' output.tab | uniq -c
    108 11
      1 14
     69 11
      1 10
     35 11
      1 16
    250 11
      1 16
```

Is there any way to fix it in Python?

---

An example of messed up lines:

```
$tail -n+108 output.tab | head -n1

CENPA   chr2    27008881.0  2701ABCD3   chr1    94883932.0  94944260.0  0.0316227766017 0.260698861451  0.277741584016  0.302602378581  0.4352790705329718  56  16


$grep -n A1 'CENPA' file1.tab

109:CENPA   chr2    27008881.0  27017455.0  1.0 0.417081004817  0.0829327365256 0.545205239241  0.7196619496326693  95  3
110-CENPO   chr2    25016174.0  25045245.0  1000.0  0.151090930896  -0.0083671250883    0.50882773122   0.0876177652747541  82  0


$grep -n 'ABCD3' file2.tab
2:ABCD3 chr1    94883932.0  94944260.0  0.0316227766017 0.260698861451  0.277741584016  0.302602378581  0.4352790705329718  56  16
```

Comment: Please show what is in `output.tab`

Comment: @Alex Belayev: see upd

Comment: unrelated: no need to call `head`, `tail` utilities -- you can select desirable lines from a file in pure Python. If you don't know how; ask. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that `subprocess.Popen()` runs asynchronously by default, and you seem to want it to run synchronously. So really, all of your `head` and `tail` commands are running at the same time, directing into the output file.

To fix this, you probably want to just add `.wait()`:

```
import subprocess
outpath = "output.tab"
with open( outpath, "w" ) as outf :
    "write a header"
    if header is True:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-n1", files[-1] ], stdout= outf, )
        p1.wait()  # Pauses the script until the command finishes
    if type(header) is str:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-n1", header ], stdout= outf,)
        p1.wait()
    for fl in files:
        print(  fl )
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n+2", fl], stdout= outf, )
        p1.wait()
```

Comment: unrelated: `subprocess.Popen(..).wait()` could be replaced with `subprocess.call(..)`